# how to export Snowflake Query result to Google Sheets without any third party extensions

Tags: google-sheets, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, export-to-excel

I want to Export the Query results from Snowflake to Google Sheets Without any Third party integrations like skyvia or seekwell , etc

does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Are you referring to a query run via Snowflake UI or programmatically?

Comment: Assume that Query is already Executed and the result is generated Programmatically 
Now i want to Export That Result directly into Google Sheets.

Comment: How is the result generated?
If you use python, it should be easy to get the data from snowflake and write it into google sheets.
If you use the Snowflake UI, you can export the result and paste it into Google Sheets.

Comment: i am using snowflake UI to Build Query in org's need and executing queries and i want without any external integrations that query (offcourse Some Sql Connection/ connectors or From functions that allows us to export is expected as solution) gets reflected in google sheets

Comment: I don't think that can be done directly. What you can do with the query results is to export them into a CSV file (COPY INTO <location>) on GCS and from there load it directly into a Google Sheet.

Comment: @Sergiu can you elaborate it more

Comment: Where is the Google Sheet located? Inside a Google account or local machine? If it's inside a Google account, then you can probably use [COPY INTO <location>](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#copy-into-location) to export directly the results of a Snowflake query into a CSV file on your Google Account storage and load it from there using Google Sheets. Have a look at the examples provided for COPY INTO <location>. If it's local machine then you can't do it directly, unless you use a programmatic way, like via a connector (Python connector for example).